# php.ini limit tricks $_FILES['userfile']['size']

Tags: php

In php.ini I have set:

```
post_max_size = 101M
upload_max_filesize = 101M
memory_limit = 128M
```

a php upload form uses can upload file up to 100M
a script will check if it doesn't exceed 100M

```
$img_size = $_FILES['bestand']['size'];
if ($img_size > MAX_EXTRA_FILE_FILE_SIZE){
$errors['tooBig'] = 1;
```

However, if a user uploads 125M, the server returns the message:
PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of ########### bytes exceeds the limit of ...
and the $error['tooBig'] will lose its value and no error message
will be returned to the user. Of course, i can just increase the ini.php:post_max_size endlessly, but even than a use could upload even larger files.

How do i tackle this?

Comment: PHP's uploading handle was always been pathetically useless. The upload completes (or is rejected) BEFORE your script is ever started up, so there's no way to monitor an in-progress upload. If you want to reject something "live", you'll need to use something else, e.g. anything OTHER than php.

Comment: @MarcB Arguably large uploads should be rejected at the web server level, you don't want to be tying up web server processes for uploads you'll just discard anyway; easy DoS opportunity. True though that PHP's behaviour doesn't really help here.

Comment: use javascript, that way you can do all of your testing and error returns before the server ever knows what's happening